# Blank screen when resuming on Ubuntu 16.04. Noveau display driver for Nvidia card. I want to use Noveau driver. I do not want privative Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

This Ubuntu 16.04 seems to work very good with my Toshiba Satellite-X205.
Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5550 @ 1.83GHz × 2.
Nvidia G84M GeForce 8700M GT
I have used Nvidia drivers, but they produce a flash on my screen constantly.
That does not occur with Noveau driver, also the resolution is better.
The issue is that when the computer goes to sleep or suspension, shows a blank screen, when resuming. I know the computer works because I handle it blindly to shut it down and turn it back on.
Is there something I can do so that feature works fine?

Comment: Remove the nvidia drivers

Comment: Hello Doug. Thanks for replying. I am not using Nvidia drivers. I am using: Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open code). That is exactly what it says on "additional controllers" tab.